# How to increase memory in Android Studio on a Mac

Tags: memory-management, android-studio, configuration

I'm having problems with my Android Studio, it is running very slow and I can see that in the bottom right corner there is a Memory usage control.

Is there a way to increase this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a configuration steps that Android recommends [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration), but for me it didn't work, so you can try so see if you have luck.

If Nothing of this works for you, try on a Mac this to see if it helps you, in the last version of Android Studio (1.2), the studio.vmoptions is inside the AndroidStudio.app in your Applications folder.

So right click or ctrl click on your AndroidStudio.App and then select show package content the studio.vmoptions is in:

Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions

Replace or change it and you will get all the RAM you need.

[image]
[image]

If you have a better answer please post it to help the community, this worked for me.

Regards.

Comment: The problem is that studio.vmoptions gets replaced every time AS updates. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154454/android-studio-keeps-replacing-studio-vmoptions-when-it-updates