# Android Studio keeps replacing studio.vmoptions when it updates

Tags: android, android-studio

I modified my studio.vmoptions to increase memory available for Android Studio. But every time I update Android Studio it complains about the file being modified and the solution it proposes is to replace the file. It doesn't let me leave the file as it is, so I have to modify studio.vmoptions every time I upgrade Android Studio (which is quite often).

Is there any other method for increasing AS heap size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this instructions to see if it helps:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

I remember that I tried this once and they said in the instructions to use an specific folder, but now the instructions says:

~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions

And I have 2 folders 1.0 and 1.2 maybe now it works in the specific version folder.